# Открытое модальное окно

Tags: html

При открытии сайта, на экране в «товарах» уже отображается модальное окно.
А мне нужно, при нажатии на кнопку оно только появлялось, как исправить?
код:

```
<style type="text/css">
#overlay {
    position: absolute;
   top: 50;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
   z-index: 1999999999;
   overflow: auto;
   visibility:hidden;
   opacity: 0;
   transition: opacity 0.7s ease-in 0s;
}
.popup {
   top: 10%;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;      
   font-size: 14px;
   margin: auto;
   width: 100%;
   min-width: 700px;
   max-width: 300px;
   position: absolute;
   padding: 50px 50px;
   border: 1px solid #ffffff;
   background-color: #fefefe;
   z-index: 1000;
   border-radius: 10px;
   font: 14px/18px 'Tahoma', Arial, sans-serif;
   box-shadow: 0 0px 14px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
.close {
   top: 10px;
   right: 10px;
   width: 32px;
   height: 32px;
   position: absolute;
   border: none;
   border-radius: 50%;
   background-color: rgba(0, 130, 230, 0.9);
   box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
   cursor: pointer;
   outline: none;
}
.close:before {
   color: rgba(0, 130, 230, 0.9);
   content: "X";
   font-family:  Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   font-size: 14px;
   font-weight: normal;
   text-decoration: none;
   text-shadow: 0 -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}
.close:hover {
   background-color: rgba(0, 130, 230, 0.9);
}
#overlay .popup p.zag{margin:20px 0 10px;padding:0 0 6px;color:black; font-size:16px;font-weight:bold;border-bottom:1px solid black;}
</style>
```

Comment: сайт https://www.gls-trade.ru

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы для popup изначально добавьте свойство в стилях display: none, далее по нажатию display: block

Comment: все ок, теперь при открытии страницы поп ап не отображается
.popup {
 display: none;
    top: 10%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;       
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 700px;
    max-width: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 50px 50px;
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;
    background-color: #fefefe;
    z-index: 1000;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font: 14px/18px 'Tahoma', Arial, sans-serif;
    box-shadow: 0 0px 14px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);

Comment: далее по нажатию display: block 
подскажите, пожалуйста, куда это вписывать?

Comment: Вам нужно создать событие в javascript файле, по клику на эту кнопку, вам знаком js?

Comment: если честно нет)))
блин, может какой то код примерный у вас есть? попробую подбить под себя

Comment: Вот тут подробно: https://medium.com/@dan.postnov/%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-javascript-30-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-dbbb599649f3